# Using MIDI file as MIDI controller -?

Tags: midi

I was thinking.
Can I create a playable MIDI file, say in Guitar Pro 6, with all the notes, tempo, measures etc, and then using this MIDI output, play the sounds in another MIDI controlled player? say KONTAKT?

What I will get is eventually a larger sound bank, as one time I'll be able to use it for fretless bass, one time for Precision Bass, and one time even for a piano, using the software third party samples.

hope my question is clear.

Thanks.

Guy

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Wouldn't it work on both Win and Mac? But if I have to choose, then OS X

Comment: Are you talking about saving a MIDI file after recording some MIDI notes, then loading that MIDI file into another application where it can be played?

Comment: No, I want the notes to be used as "commands" to the other software's sound banks.
I managed to do so using Finale -> Kontakt.

Comment: Telling from your own answer: what you want to do here is basically the whole point of the MIDI standard: you can use MIDI files/data in any MIDI compatible context. There is nothing host/software/hardware specific about the MIDI data. You can export MIDI files from Guitar Pro and use in any other host and then hook up VSTi plugins to produce output. MIDI data is nothing but "commands".

Answer (score 1):

- OS X has the built-in IAC (inter-application communication) driver that can loop back the output of one application to the input of another application.
- Linux has the built-in "Midi Through" port.
- Windows has nothing built in. You have to install a separater driver such as [loopMIDI](http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html) or [LoopBe1](http://nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting to know the IAC. To be more specific, can I use a MIDI file that represent my notes to control another application? (e.g Guitar Pro 6 -> MIDI File -> NI KONTAKT Samples?

Answer (score -1):

OK, I worked a solution.

Using the transcription software "Finale" I loaded a midi file generated in "Guitar Pro". I can just as well write the notes directly in "Finale".
Then, in "Finale", go to the MIDI/Audio Menu and make sure the option "Play Finale Through Audio Unit" is checked.
Go to Window menu, and open the mixer. Then, in the Mixer panel choose "INST(rument). LIST" and for every instrument, under "Device" choose your sampler, in this case KONTAKT 5.

Hope it helps.